How can I disable Thunderbird's colored quote bar function for HTML emails?
I would like to disable the colored quote bars Thunderbird adds automatically for displaying HTML emails.
How can I do that in a current Thunderbird version (v115+) without using addons and without userchrome.css ?
Is there a config setting to disable this function ?
I already tried setting mail.quoted_graphical to false to no avail.

Rationale: I like this function for plain text messages, but dislike it for HTML messages, because I want to see what I really send (WYSIWYG) and what the recipient receives, to the extent possible. And these colored quote bars (excerpt bars) are not encoded in the message, so the recipient won't see them.

Try in about:config check settings and set these values (which I believe are default values):
mailnews.display.html_as = 0
mailnews.display.original_text = true

